# Cannot get TimeZone to show long name instead of abbreviation (Xamarin Android)

Tags: c#, android, timezone, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm trying to get the long name for the timezone from `System.TimeZone`. This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
Console.WriteLine(System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.DaylightName);
```

And the result that i'm getting in console is

> EST

But what I need is the long name:

> Eastern Standard Time

I looked into C# documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone(v=vs.110).aspx) and noticed that the .Net library is returning what I need but for some reason Xamarin (mono) just gives me the **abbreviation**.

Is there a way around that?

Comment: I get the same thing in iOS.  I'd suggest submitting a bug: bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: Thanks @Jason! I just reported it... Meanwhile I'm looking into a trouble-free workaround :)

Comment: Are you looking for a human readable display name? Or are you looking for the time zone id to pass back to a service?

Comment: @MattJohnson Human readable. I've already found a solution using the TimeZoneInfo, I'll post the answer tomorrow.

Comment: @P.Sami I'm currently experiencing this - did you report the bug?

Comment: Found bug report (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=18804) - it doesn't look like this will be fixed

Comment: @Aaron that's actually my bug report... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day, I went through a lot of pain to figure this out and ended up with a converter on the **Web** and **NOT** on the **android or  device**:

```
    private TimeZoneInfo ConvertTimeZone(string timeZoneString)
    {
        ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> timeZoneInfos = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
        if (Regex.IsMatch(timeZoneString, "[A-Z]{3,5}[0-9]{0,2}") && !Regex.IsMatch(timeZoneString, "[A-Z]{3,5}[-]{1}[0-9]{0,2}"))
        {
            List<string> abbreviations = new List<string>();

            // create the list of abbreviations for TimeZoneInfos
            timeZoneInfos.ToList().ForEach(
                x =>
            {
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(x.StandardName, "[A-Z0-9]{3,4,5}"))
                {
                    string fullString = x.StandardName.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
                    string[] split = Regex.Split(fullString, "[a-z]|[()-.]");
                    abbreviations.Add(string.Concat(split));
                }
            });

            return timeZoneInfos[abbreviations.IndexOf(timeZoneString)];
        }
        else
        {
            return timeZoneInfos.Where(x => x.StandardName == timeZoneString).First();
        }
    }
```

The purpose of this was to get to show my data on the Map with the correct time zone and this did it.

**Warning:** This will probably work on most of the North American time zones but I cannot guarantee that it will work all across the world. Windows does have 102 time-zones and I just tested a few. I basically created a map for abbreviations.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit older, but for those who needs to get the timezone name use

```
Java.Util.TimeZone.Default.ID
```

This will give the timezone name.